# How to package custom Python scripts into module

Tags: python, python-2.7

For now I plan on dropping in my custom modules into `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ocd/`. I have 3 files in the folder (see below).

```
__init__.py
ocd.py
ocd_logging.py
```

Content of `__init__.py`

```
from ocd import *
from ocd_logging import *
```

Everything works fine, I can run my scripts in my own folder that import the `ocd` module. However, I'm not able to run scripts that depend on the `ocd_logging` module? I decided to "package" them together because `ocd` also imports `ocd_logging`. Do I need to separate `ocd_logging` into it's own path?

## ocd.py

```
import smtplib
import logging,hiplogging
import os,sys,re
import consul,serf
import rpm
import datetime
import ConfigParser
import pprint
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr
from pymongo import MongoClient
from rpmUtils.miscutils import stringToVersion
from ocd_logging import *
```

## ocd_logging.py

```
import logging
import hiplogging
```

Comment: No, are you importing `ocd` in the `ocd_logging` module? If so, that might be causing problems.

Comment: If possible can you paste the import section from both the .py files?

Comment: updated with import section for both files.